# As per oAuth2.0 authentication should happen in device native browser, then why all known apps having native login screens

Tags: android, ios, mobile, oauth, oauth-2.0

This is something very confusing and I cant find any solution for this, as per oAuth 2.0 guidelines for mobile integration,

> OAuth 2.0 authorization requests from native apps should only be made
> through external user-agents, primarily the user's browser.  This specification details the security and usability reasons.

Ref: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252

Both Facebook and Twitter have native login screens, can we say they are not following the oAuth guidelines or is their any other approach which complies with oAuth guidelines where we can use native login screens?

Also are there any native apps where we can see the oAuth guidelines followed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The primary reason for using an external user agent is that it prevents the app from having access to the user credentials.  If the app presents "username" and "password" fields on its own screen then it is possible for a malicious developer to steal those credentials.

In the case of Facebook/Twitter and similar, the user is not using their credentials to authenticate to a 3rd party system, but rather the relying party and the authenticating party are the same.

This means that Facebook, for example, do not gain any more access to the user's data if they did steal the user's credentials as the data is on their servers. Presumably they also trust their own development processes to ensure that rogue code has not been injected into the app.

From the user perspective, they also trust the app (assuming they're installed it from a trustworthy source as as the App Store) and expect to be able to log in within the app.  Being pushed out to a web browser would not be the best user experience.

Indeed, it is likely that the Facebook etc apps don't even use an OAuth flow; they don't need to for their own users.

For an OAuth flow where an app is not created by the authenticating party themselves, an external user agent should be used; the user should not trust the app with their credentials.

For web based OAuth on iOS, Apple recommends using `SFSafariViewController` to present the login process within the app; this eliminates the user "bouncing" out of the app, into the system browser and then back to the app, while ensuring that the app code does not have any access to the user's activities in the  web session.